# How to draw shapes in maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to draw shapes on maps line in rectangle or circle of the user if the user goes beyond this line alert message should be indicate him that he is beyond the boundary should( with 20or 30kms).

This can help user to get back to his boundary line.

If anyone have idea about this please help me guys.

Comment: did you even look at the documentation? There is a section on how to draw on the map

Comment: [Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) has very nice documentation, you can find everything you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it's for circle:

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
  .center(eventCentre)
  .radius(event.radius * CONVERT_KM_METERS)
  .fillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.map_radius_fill))
  .strokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.map_radius_stroke))
  .strokeWidth(3);
map.addCircle(circleOptions);
```